# SSIS Package Not Moving Files When Executed in CMD

Tags: ssis

I am trying to import bulk text files (more than 100, 000) into a SQL database. I have created an SSIS package to do that. The package has a File System Task which is supposed to move the files imported to the database to another location (archive folder). This helps in case there is an error during importation so am able to identify where the job stopped.

When i execute the package in SSIS (Visual Studio), the files are being imported and moved.

When i however, execute the package in CMD, the package is only importing the files but not moving.

I have tried to run CMD as administrator but it has not worked as i thought that it was an issue with permissions.

Comment: Since the move alone is failing, one possible issue could be with your "destination folder or file path". Are you using any "relative paths" ? In that case, the folder from which you run the package would have an influence. Or If the destination path is dynamically constructed, you can check the value of the constructed path.